# How to convert a number to percentage and get a decimal

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, calculator, percentage

I am working on programming a calculator in JavaFX. How do I go about getting the percentage of a number in decimal form? For example
45% would give 0.45
2% would give me 0.02
etc.
Thanks

This would just return the whole number that the user enters, such as
45% would be 45
2% would be 2
etc.

```
            bt1.setOnAction(e->{
                    String result = textArea.getText(); 
                    double n = Double.parseDouble(result);
                    double percent = n * 100 / 100;
                    textArea.appendText(Double.toString(percent));
            });
```

Comment: `n * 100 / 100` is just `n`. If you want to convert the percentage to decimal form, you just divide by 100.

Comment: Divide it by 100?

Comment: It should be `double percent = n/100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bt1.setOnAction(e->{
String result = textArea.getText(); 
String replaceString = result.replace("%","");
double n = Double.parseDouble(replaceString);
double percent = n / 100;
textArea.appendText(Double.toString(percent));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line:
double percent = n * 100 / 100;
to 
double percent = n / 100;